# Flutter Duplicate global key when navigating to original route working with Persistence navigation

Tags: flutter

I am an Android developer, new to flutter. I wanted persistence bottom nav in my app. So I implemented it. But I didn't need the bar in Videoplayer.

**"homepage>> episodepage >> videoplayer."**

So I implemented the following solution.

```
  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PlayerPage(widget.list[index])));
```

which worked perfectly, But another problem was raised, back pressed closed the app. I didn't find the solution to go back to episodesPage() . but I manage to make it work with a small trick.

So, I created a variable in class C

```
  static Widget? MainPage;
```

Then on my Main inside Myapp() I assign the variable

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

Widget MainPage = MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page');


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

C.MainPage= MainPage;   // here

return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: MainPage,
); }}
```

And then on **VideoPlayer()** inside **WillPopScope**. I was able to navigate back to my previous Episode() page.

```
   Widget? child = C.MainPage;

    if (child != null) {
      Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
          .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => child));
    }
```

It is working perfectly. But when I check logs an error was showing. How should I remove the error? or what's the better solution.

The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.

```
The following GlobalKey was specified multiple times in the widget tree. This will lead to parts of the widget tree being truncated unexpectedly, because the second time a key is seen, the previous instance is moved to the new location. The key was:
- [LabeledGlobalKey<NavigatorState>#a352a]
This was determined by noticing that after the widget with the above global key was moved out of its previous parent, that previous parent never updated during this frame, meaning that it either did not update at all or updated before the widget was moved, in either case implying that it still thinks that it should have a child with that global key.
The specific parent that did not update after having one or more children forcibly removed due to GlobalKey reparenting is:
- NavigatorTab(state: _NavigatorTab#34e63)
A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      BuildOwner.finalizeTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2991:15)
#1      BuildOwner.finalizeTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3016:8)
#2      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:893:19)
#3      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:370:5)
#4      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1146:15)
#5      SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1083:9)
#6      SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:997:5)
#10     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#11     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#12     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
```